# How to discover which Jar or package creates Objects

Tags: java, tomcat, object, memory

My question seems pretty simple but I haven't found a solution.

I need to know how deployed packages inside Tomcat consume memory.

I tried some tools like VisualVM and JConsole but I can't discover which of my deployed package creates the objects. For example, I can see there are a lot of `java.lang.String` objects but I need to know from which package/JAR they have been created.

THX for editing omg... so prooooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try and use  [MAT(Memory Analyzer Tool)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)
With this tool you can inspect heapdumps taken with VisualVM for instance... For each Object in your heap you can view which objects have a reference to this object and thus which objects prevent other objects from being garbage collected

Comment: thx man this should do the trick, I tried to take a heap dump with jmap and open it, I think this should be what developers asked me, I will let u know....

Comment: very nice u can use oql language with this eclipse tool, thx guys

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **Object Query Language (OQL)** for querying the heap. Maybe that will help your purpose.

You can refer to this link and see if you get what you need.
[Object Query Language in VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/oqlhelp.html)

Comment: thx anyway man I tried with the MAT tool that bvanvelse suggested me and it should work, this is interesting too but I haven't understood where to launch these queries.

Comment: VisualVM has the option of firing queries on the heap. there is a console for the same in it.

Comment: [Example of OQL with VisualVM](http://blog.lesc.se/2012/02/how-to-extract-data-from-java-heap-dump.html)

Comment: oh this seems nice, can't vote this up cus I have no reputation but I will suggest this solutions to developers, thx !